# I want to purchase this jacket for my son but it has this symbol on it. Can you help? I have a picture!

Tags: translation

[image]

Help what does this symbol on this jacket mean?

Comment: `悟` - [悟空](https://www.google.com/search?q=悟空&tbm=isch) / [Dragon Ball (anime)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_(anime))

Comment: This jacket looks awesome!

Answer (score 2):

悟 (wù) is a buddhist concept, especially in chán (禅), and means "realize", "awaken", especially in the word 悟空 (wùkōng): awake in the emptiness of existence.

The monkey 孙悟空 (Sun Wukong) is a character in the classic novel Journey to the West, and is often portrayed in Chinese and East Asian culture. The same goes for many other buddhist concepts.

In this instance, it is related to Japanese manga.

Answer (score 1):

I come from Taiwan.

I think your jacket symbol was from a comic that name is "Dragon Ball".

[image]

Comment: Once you uploaded the image, you didn't have to post the link :)

Comment: Don't worry!You can try to google the "Dragon Ball"or"七龍珠",then you will find a lot of the photo!

GOOGLE "七龍珠 孫悟空"

Answer (score 0):

"悟" has the meaning of "think", but far more than that. In Chinese, 悟 is always related to Zen. 
  If you watched Kung Fu Panda 3 before, could you remember Po tried to 悟 something but he just cannot do that at first? 
  Because 悟 is a really hard thing to do. You can 想(think) a Math question, but you cannot use 悟 with it. Only when the thinking is related to yourself, the nature, the world even the universe and you try to figure out something mentally, you can use 悟.

[image]

For example, when you try to understand this picture(the Eight Diagrams), you are trying to 悟 something rather than 想(think) something.

All in all, this is a good jacket. But I think this 悟 just a abbreviation of Wu(悟)kong(空).

Comment: The picture was 太極 but not 八卦. And I think the point digressed a little from the question.